# what is the command to retrieve the installed application/packages via command line in windows?

Tags: windows

Is there a command to retrieve the installed application/packages via command line in windows 2003. i.e to get the details of Add/remove programs via the command line same as 'rpm -qa ' in linux.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing built in, really. However, the PStools suite from Sysinternals is an invaluable set of software, available free from Microsoft, and they have a commmand for this.

```
Psinfo.exe -s
```

Comment: the tool worked Great

Comment: Woah, he selected an answer!!

Comment: It's possible that he didn't know how the site worked, given that he had answered *none* of them until today. Just a little education :-)

Answer (score 3):

Try the [PStools](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649) package and use the Psinfo command with the -s switch.

Answer (score 2):

If we're using the same requirements as [Command-Line Kung-Fu](http://blog.commandlinekungfu.com/), then the closest we can get is the following:

```
reg query hklm\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\uninstall /s | find "DisplayName"
```

Notably, this doesn't exclude Windows updates, which the built-in Add/Remove Programs application does. You could do this exclusively from the command line, but it'd be considerably more complicated.